# XSLT Stylesheet works with a vbs script, but not Perl

Tags: perl, xslt, vbscript

I have a program that is essentially a search application, and it exists in both VBScript and Perl form (I'm trying to make an executable with a GUI).

Currently the search application outputs an HTML file, and if a section of text in the HTML is longer than twelve lines then it hides anything after that and includes a clickable `More...` tag.

This is done in XSLT and works with VBScript.

I literally copied and pasted the stylesheet into the Perl program that I'm using and it does everything right except for the `More...` tag.

Is there any reason why it would be working with the VBScript but not Perl?

I'm using [`XML::LibXSLT`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXSLT) in the Perl script, and here is the template that is supposed to be creating the `More...` tag

```
<xsl:template name="more">

  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="row-id"/>
  <xsl:param name="cycle" select="1"/>

  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="($cycle &gt; 12) and contains($text,'&#13;')">
      <span class="show" onclick="showID('SHOW{$row-id}');style.display = 'none';">More...</span>
      <span class="hidden" id="SHOW{$row-id}">
        <xsl:call-template name="highlight">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </span>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#13;')">
      <xsl:call-template name="highlight">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text,'&#13;')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="more">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#13;')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="row-id" select="$row-id"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="cycle" select="$cycle + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="highlight">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>

  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What are you using to process the XSLT? It could be that you are relying on unspecified behaviour or that one implementation has a bug. Or you might have forgotten an option, who knows. To make your question answerable, you have to add XSLT processor information, and ideally some code that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @amon I added code and the perl module that I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your XSLT is searching the text for `CR` characters - `&#13;`.

Windows files use the `CR LF` character pair to terminate each line of text, and a version of Perl running on a Windows system will strip the `CR` to leave just the `LF`.

This provides an API compatible with Linux-like systems, which use just `LF` in the first place, but means your XSLT stylesheet doesn't find any `CR` characters when it looks for them.

I suggest you change your stylesheet to search instead for `LF` characters, which will be present at the end of every line regardless of the file's origin, and will be seen by both Perl and VBScript.

I think character codes are best expressed in hex, so you would change `'&#13;` to `'&#x0A;` throughout your XSLT code.

**Note**

By making this change your strings will be left with a trailing `CR` after you use `substring-before($text, '&#x0A;')`. You can either leave this in place — I don't think it will do any harm as it won't be rendered by a browser — or you can remove from the string that you pass to the `more` template when you call it

```
<xsl:call-template name="more">
  <xsl:with-parameter name="text" value="translate($text, '&#x0D;', '')"/>
  ...
</xsl:call-template>
```

That would leave the template with a clean string to process, containing no `CR` characters.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it works (without changing anything within my template call.